# how to declare a node of a list that each node is a two dimentional matrix

Tags: c#, list, matrix

I have a list like this:

```
List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
Node s = new Node();
```

`Node s` is a two diementinal array, how do I declare that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to have a list of two-dimensional arrays, you can do this:

```
// Declare a list of matrices.
List<int[,]> matrixList = new List<int[,]>();
// Add a matrix to the list.
matrixList.Add(new int[5, 5]);
```

Comment: @naimeh: the dimensions don't necessarily have to be compile-time constants. If you have an `int` variable, say, `int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`, it's OK to write `matrixList.Add(new int[a, a]);`. If an already created matrix should be able to grow/shrink at runtime, then you might consider using lists of lists or, perhaps, some custom `Matrix` classes instead of arrays.

Comment: I want that each node have a string name and have a two dimentional array  how should  i show that

Comment: @naimeh: You should create your own class (e.g. `Node`) and declare two properties there: `public string Name { get; set; }` and `public int[,] Matrix { get; set; }`. Something like that. In this case, the declaration of list will be `List<Node> list = new List<Node>()`.